# EntityFramework : Invalid column name *_ID1

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement DbContext for couple of tables called '`Employee`' and '`Department`'
Relationship between Employee and Department is many to one.  i.e. department can have many employees.

Below are the EntityFramework classes I designed ( CodeFirst approach )

```
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column("Department_ID")]        
        public int Department_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Department")]
    public class Department
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("Name")]        
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee>  Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

While adding Employee record I am getting below exception

```
"Invalid column name 'Department_ID1'."
```

I am not sure why EF is referring to `Department_ID1`.  Do I need to add configuration in `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext`?

I am using EF version `6.1.1`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi After spending some time I could fix this problem by using `ForeignKey` attribute on `public virtual Department Department { get; set; }` property of `Employee` class.

Please see below code.

```
 [Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("Department_ID")]        
    public int Department_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department_ID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

This fixed my problem.  Are there any other solution to fix this?  Using fluent API?

Answer (score 20):

I've also gotten this problem in my `EF` `one-many` deals where the `one` has a `List` of the `many` property and my mapping didn't specify that property. For example take:

```
public class Notification
{
    public long ID { get; set; }     

    public IList<NotificationRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
public class NotificationRecipient
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long NotificationID { get; set; }

    public Notification Notification { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my mapping, the way that caused the `Exception` (the **incorrect** way):

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Notification).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.NotificationID);
```

What fixed it (the **correct** way) was specifying the `WithMany` property:

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Notification).WithMany(x => x.Recipients)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.NotificationID);
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, the issue was resolved by removing a (duplicate?) virtual property.

Using the OP's example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Department_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee>  Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Turns into:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Department_ID { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee>  Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 This solution can be easy to overlook, but in cases where VS generates the context for you it sometimes decides to create property names that don't match the original names.  You then end up with a duplicate when you add it manually thinking it's missing.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I added a virtual property on top of the auto generated property
I fixed it by adding the NotMapped attribute to my property, or you could configure with fluent api

```cs
    public partial class Control
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<Control> Children { get => this.InverseParent; set => this.InverseParent = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, my issue was the FK was a `long` but I had it as an `int` in the model. EF generated a new column because it didn't match types on the FK so it assumed they weren't the same and went ahead with making another one but putting  1 at the end because there was already one with the proper name. Making sure the types matched resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed simply by putting `[NotMapped]` annotation on your virtual properties.

```
public class Employee
{
    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int Department_ID
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

And in you modelBuilder:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Department);
        });
```

Just flip this around if you want to call by Department.

We use the `[NotMapped]` annotation so that EF Core will disregard it when looking at your database.